# Python For Look with Condition

Tags: python, oracle

I am looking to create a folder with an excel for each and would like to isolate data based on specific email addresses in rows. How can I use the SQL statement and or Create excel into different folders with a for loop (conditional/where clause)

```
orc_con = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx/xxx@xxxx.world')
SQL_Statement = 'select * from PYTHON_TEST' 
df_ora = pd.read_sql(SQL_Statement, con=orc_con)
for i in df_ora.itertuples():
    print(i)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('XXXXX_Monthly_Claims.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_ora.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CCBHC',index=False)
# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Data']
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to make it more clear what you are actually trying to do? From what I can guess, you expect a number of email addresses in a specific column, and want to dump all the rows with the same email into one file each, is that correct?

Comment: Presumably you want to switch on different values for one of the columns in that loop? If there are a small number of hardcoded values, just do `if i[3] == ‘spam’:` ... `elif i[3] == ‘eggs’:` etc. and write to a different file in each branch. If there are a lot, or they’re not known in advance (say you want to write it to an excel file with the name `spam.xls` or `cheese.xls` or whatever happens to be in `i[3]`), you’ll probably want to create a dict that maps strings to Excel files.

Comment: ... or, better, since you’re using Pandas, have Pandas group the results by `i[3]` and loop over the groups instead of all rows.

Comment: Yes< for instance I have 2 rows 3 columns 1 column has an email address of X and the other 2 y. I would like to create separate dataframes based on those email address filters( similar to a where clause)  so dataframe_x = 1 row and Dataframe_y has the 2 other